# I have written query to sort name starting with S and V in give database , error coming up is below

Tags: mysql

```
select * from cricket_1111 , cricket_999 
where first_name LIKE "s%v" 
LIMIT 0, 1000
```

> Error Code: 1052. Column 'first_name' in where clause is ambiguous 0.000 sec

Comment: LIMIT is a specific MySQL keyword. Not a SQL Server's one ! The right command (ISO SQL) is OFFSET ... FETCH ... that MySQL does not have...

Comment: It's *long* past time you stopped using that 31 year old JOIN syntax, by the way.  It was superseded some 29 years ago.

Comment: @larnu this old syntax come in 1972 by Boyce and Chamberlin... So not 31 but 39... ! In IBM laboratories for SystemR

Comment: @SQLPro I am talking about the ANSI-89 syntax... -_- Still, 29 is 29, and always will be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `first_name` column in both tables, so you have to specify which table you want to use like

```
select * 
from cricket_1111 , cricket_999 
where cricket_1111.first_name LIKE "s%v" 
LIMIT 0, 1000
```

> It would also be very productive if you took a look at the JOIN syntax rather than using `from cricket_1111 , cricket_999`

Something like

```
select * 
from cricket_1111 c1
    JOIN cricket_999 c9 on c9.link_column = c1.link_column
where c_1.first_name LIKE "s%v" 
LIMIT 0, 1000 
ORDER BY c_1.first_name
```

> Also a limit clause without a sort `ORDER BY` can be very unpredictabe

Comment: Thank You so much.. Your solution worked !

Answer (score 0):

Your error is due to the fact that the colum first_name appears in the two table. And the SQL engine cannot make an arbitrary choice ! You need to prefix the column name by the table name in the ORDER clause of the SELECT statement.